# How to organise shared model helpers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have two models which has similar slug generation methods. As shown below:

```
def generate_reference
    self_id = self.id.present? ? (sprintf '%04d', self.id) : '0000'
    [
        REFERENCE_CODE[:request], 
        Time.now.strftime('%Y%M'),
        Time.now.strftime('%S%2N')].join('-')
end

def remake_slug
    self.update_attribute(:reference, nil)
    self.save!
end
```

The only thing that will change will be `REFERENCE_CODE[:request]`. It is different in different models. Example:

**request.rb**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :generate_reference, use: :slugged, slug_column: 'reference'
after_create :remake_slug

def generate_reference
   [REFERENCE_CODE[:request]...]
end

def remake_slug
    self.update_attribute(:reference, nil)
    self.save!
end
```

and in **booking.rb**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :generate_reference, use: :slugged, slug_column: 'reference'
after_create :remake_slug

def generate_reference
   [REFERENCE_CODE[:booking]...]
end

def remake_slug
    self.update_attribute(:reference, nil)
    self.save!
end
```

There is a huge amount of code that is repetitive. I am wondering how I should organise the slug creation logic to make it cleaner?